# MySql Inster Trigger

Tags: mysql

Please, help me. I never had deal with SQL before.
I have 2 tables : Object , Posts;

### Objects:

1. ObjName
2. Adress
3. PostsAmount

| Microsoft Corporation | Redmond, WA 98052-7329 | 0 |

### Posts:

1. ObjName
2. humans

---

I need to make this :
Then I INSERT in 'posts' new raw, **'Objects'** table must update ***PostsAmount*** to count() of raws in 'posts' where 'ObjName' is the same as inserted.

Sry about my engl. Please help, cant handle it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need something like this:

```
DELEIMTER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_Posts_ins
AFTER INSERT
   ON Posts FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   SELECT count(1) INTO @countObj from Posts where ObjName = NEW.ObjName;
   UPDATE Objects set PostsAmount = @countObj where ObjName = NEW.ObjName;

END$$
DELIMETER ;
```

But I would suggest that instead of a trigger, you update the Objects once every so often (like 5 mins) as triggers can have a performance overhead.